# Axios request - Firebase Cloud functions - Error : could not handle the request

Tags: firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe checkout into my ecommerce website (developped with VueJS and Firebase).

This is my checkout script :

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
var stripe = Stripe(
  "pk_test_51INdvGD9cbEc0vgt2LTeZ81ZFuqapXTBYP6tQuFSrm61zvmjzUxc61NEf3vsNOXJpmJa8qeFQ1OOZeetNknJVLq600xUZ4koaP"
);
export default {
  name: "Checkout",
  data() {
    return {
      sessionId: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    pay() {
      
      let data = this.$store.state.cart.map(item => ({[item.product_id] : item.productQuantity}));

      data = Object.assign({}, ...data);

      // console.log(data);
      axios.get(
          "https://us-central1-shop-vue-c6c23.cloudfunctions.net/CheckoutSession",
          {
            params: {
              products : data
            }
          }
        )
        .then(response => {
          this.sessionId = response.data
          console.log(this.sessionId.id);
          console.log(response.data);
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({
              sessionId: this.sessionId.id
            })
            .then(function(result) {});
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And this is my firebase cloud function "CheckoutSession" :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_***');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
exports.CheckoutSession = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  cors(request, response, () => {
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://shop-vue-c6c23.web.app');
    
    let myProducts =  request.query.products;

    myProducts = Object.entries(JSON.parse(myProducts));
    
     response.send(myProducts);

    const productArray = [];
  
    myproducts.forEach(item => {
        const p = admin.firestore().doc(`products/&{item[0]}`).get();
        productArray.push(p);
    });

    const all = await Promise.all(productArray);

    const results = [];

    all.forEach(item => {
      const data = {};

      data.amount = parseFloat(item.data().price);
      data.currency = "eur";
      data.description = item.data().description;
      data.name = item.data().name;

      myproducts.forEach(q => {
        if(item.id == q[0]){
          data.quantity = q[1];
        }
      });
      results.push(data);
    });

    stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: results,
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
    cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
      }, function(err, session) {
        response.send(session);
      });
   });
});
```

So as you seen the title my error is
" Error: could not handle the request "

On the other hand, I understand that the details which should be passed from my checkout to the stripe checkout doesn't work but it's undefined. Is it because the checkoutsession link doesn't work ?

Comment: Are there any more details about the error?  Like a stack trace?

Comment: I don't have any other details about this error. This is why I'm blocked.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Not much can be done without more details.

Comment: can  you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?